# Error: 'winrt::to_hstring' None of the '13' overloads could convert all the argument types

Tags: c++-winrt, winui-3

i have in `HeadersControl.idl` below:

```
...
[default_interface]
runtimeclass HeadersControl : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.UserControl
{
    HeadersControl();
    Int32 MyProperty;

    static Microsoft.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty TitleProperty{ get; };
    IInspectable Title;

    ...

}
...
```

`HeadersControl.xaml`

```
//HeadersControl.xaml
<UserControl
    x:Class="TD2_WinUI3.HeadersControl"
    ...        
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        ...
        <Grid x:Name="headerRoot" Padding="{Binding ElementName=headerControl, Path=Padding}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid x:Name="pageTitle" Background="Transparent" Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Canvas x:Name="ShadowHost" Opacity="{x:Bind ShadowOpacity, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="TitleTextBlock"
                    Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="{Binding ElementName=headerControl, Path=FontSize}"
                    Foreground="{Binding ElementName=headerControl, Path=Foreground}"
                    Text="{x:Bind Title, Mode=OneWay}"
                    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                    TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        ...
</UserControl>
```

then in the `HeadersControl.xaml.h`

```
...
namespace winrt::TD2_WinUI3::implementation
{
    struct HeadersControl : HeadersControlT<HeadersControl>
    {
        HeadersControl();

        Windows::Foundation::IInspectable Title() 
        {
            return GetValue(m_titleProperty);
        }
        void Title(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& value)
        {
            SetValue(m_titleProperty, winrt::box_value(value));
        }
        static  Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty TitleProperty() { return m_titleProperty; }

        ...

    private:
        static Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty m_titleProperty;
        ...
    };
}

namespace winrt::TD2_WinUI3::factory_implementation
{
    struct HeadersControl : HeadersControlT<HeadersControl, implementation::HeadersControl>
    {
    };
}
```

and in `HeadersControl.xaml.cpp`

```
namespace winrt::TD2_WinUI3::implementation
{
    HeadersControl::HeadersControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ...
    }

    Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty HeadersControl::m_titleProperty = Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty::Register
    (
            L"Title",
            winrt::xaml_typename<Windows::Foundation::IInspectable>(),
            winrt::xaml_typename<TD2_WinUI3::HeadersControl>(),
            Microsoft::UI::Xaml::PropertyMetadata{ nullptr }
    );

    ...
}
```

I'm getting the following errors, but as far as I can tell I've matched my dependency porperties exactly.
the complete error codes are:

```
Error C2665 'winrt::to_hstring': none of the 13 overloads could convert all the argument types (compiling source file Generated Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp)   TD2 WinUI3  C:\Users\...\source\repos\TD2 WinUI3\TD2 WinUI3\Generated Files\HeadersControl.xaml.g.hpp   211
```

and

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2660 'winrt::TD2_WinUI3::implementation::HeadersControlT<winrt::TD2_WinUI3::implementation::HeadersControl>::HeadersControl_obj1_Bindings::Set_Microsoft_UI_Xaml_Controls_TextBlock_Text': function does not take 1 arguments (compiling source file Generated Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp) TD2 WinUI3  C:\Users\...\source\repos\TD2 WinUI3\TD2 WinUI3\Generated Files\HeadersControl.xaml.g.hpp   211
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with XAML's property system, but your `TitleProperty` is read-only. Could this be causing the issue?

Comment: It's an identifier, a constant value to identify the property `Title`. Following the Documentation: Dependency property identifier is typically public and read-only. But what do you mean by "This be causing the issue" ?

Comment: Property getters and setters in the C++/WinRT projection share the same name, but take zero or one argument, respectively. The error message suggests, that the compiler can find the property, but cannot find an overload that takes one argument. Hence my guess that this is somehow caused by a read-only property. Regardless of that, can you strip down the example to its bare minimum as well as provide the full error diagnostic?

Comment: here you are! however, i dig a bit further and i think i should had pass the title inside `IVector` list or a collection resource.

Comment: The TextBlock.Text attribute expects a string. But you bound it to Title, which is an IInspectable. The compiler is trying to convert an IInspectable to a string but can't figure out how. Your Title property probably should be a string.

Comment: i used both ways indexing the header of navigation view. the normal one described in doc of winui3 [c++/winrt] and the other alternative one used inside the xaml control gallery project. the second one used to bind to the title(Header) as an object(IInspectable), that's why i got that error. thanks guys, i should have chose one method not both.